# Reset Shared Preference File after a specific time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey what's up all of you. I am currently developing an app and I am interested in how to reset only **one** file from Shared Preference after **24 hours**. Hoping someone can help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that [schedules](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) the execution of a runnable with

```
context.getSharedPreferences("pref_file", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

after 24 hours.
Something like:

```
    //...
    private ScheduledFuture mHandle;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    //...
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Runnable deleteIt = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getSharedPreferences("pref_file", 0).edit().clear().commit();
                mHandle.cancel(false); //don't cancel here if you want it to run every 24 hours
            }
        };
        if(mHandle == null)
            mHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(deleteIt, 60 * 60 * 24, 60 * 60 * 24, SECONDS);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    //...
```

You could also use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/java/util/Timer.html).